# How to log Client IP and X-Forwarded-For IP in tomcat access log

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers, ip, load-balancing

How to log Client IP and X-Forwarded-For IP in tomcat access log.

I am using %{X-Forwarded-For}i and it logs the actual client address if I access through load balancer. But does not log the actual client address if I directly access the tomcat instance. Is there a way to display the actual client IP address in both the cases?

Answer (score 15):

From http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html:

> If you are running a version of tomcat greater than version 6.0.21 or tomcat 7, you can take advantage of the new Remote IP Valve. For access logging, the nice thing about this valve is that it will swap the client IP with an IP address passed with the X-Forwarded-For header—automatically—if an IP address is passed in the X-Forwarded-For header.  Loading it is pretty easy. Just add the org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve to your server.xml before your AccessLogValve declaration. For example:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

  <!-- Remote IP Valve -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />

  <!-- Access log processes all example.
    Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
    prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
    pattern="combined" resolveHosts="false"/>
  -->
</Host>
```

> If you are using a version of tomcat 6 older than 6.0.21 and you want to store the X-Forwarded-For IP address instead, then you could modify the pattern property of your AccessLogValve. You'll need to remove the "common" or "combined" pattern and replace it with one of the following patterns:

```
Common Log Format: %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t "%r" %s %b
Combined Log Format: %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t %r %s %b %{User-Agent}i %{Referer}i
```

> The main problem here, that RemoteIP Valve does take care of, is that you'll only get the X-Forwarded-For address in the logs. If you hit the app server directly, bypassing the device that is inserting the X-Forwarded-For header in the request, you won't get an IP address logged.  You will still log a request—you just will not know where it came from.

Comment: This works when going through the load balancer, but it is not logging the IP address when accessing the tomcat instnace directly skipping the load balancer URL. Is there a way to log IP address in both the cases?

Comment: You will also need to set `requestAttributesEnabled` attribute to `true` in AccessLogValue.

Comment: The linked article does not mention the need for adding `requestAttributesEnabled="true"` to `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" ... />`, though as @sandeepd says, this _is_ crucial to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue using an Apache reverse proxy in front of a Java application running on Tomcat/9.0.12

I fixed it by adding this to Tomcat conf/server.xml , where to place the valve will depend on weather you want to apply this per Engine/Host/Context , i have added this 2 valves

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="tomcat_access_log" suffix=".log" pattern="%t %{X-AUSERNAME}o %{User-Agent}i %a %m %r %b %s %D %I %{x-forwarded-for}i" />
```

you don't need to define all remoteIpHeader and protocolHeader as these are the default values but I have added them just for clarity reason https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html

%a will show the proxy ip(or load-balancer) and %{x-forwarded-for}i will show the user ip

Comment: Does case sensitive for `x-forwarded-for`?

Comment: @YuJiaao  http headers are not case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" />

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    requestAttributesEnabled="true"
     pattern="Remote Ip is: %{org.apache.tomcat.remoteAddr}r" />
```

You can add these two Valve definition into context.xml. So you can see remote ip in both case. Through load balancer or direct.

org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve detects "x-forwarded-for" header. If there is "x-forwarded-for" in header puts its value into "org.apache.tomcat.remoteAddr" request attribute. If there is no  "x-forwarded-for" in header puts client ip addr into "org.apache.tomcat.remoteAddr" request attribute.

AccessLogValve config just logs "org.apache.tomcat.remoteAddr" request attribute which holds correct remote ip.

Comment: Both of them supports Valve definitions.  If you need to that for all apps that works on tomcat you need to  do it in server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answers already provided here, it is possible to also exclude logging the checks from your load balancer.

When the request passes through `RemoteIpValve`, if the request had an `X-Forwarded-For` header (or whatever you have configured for `remoteIpHeader`), an attribute is added to the request called `org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.RemoteAddr`. You can then use this in `AccessLogValve` to log only if this attribute is present.

This example works with tomcat9.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    directory="logs"
    prefix="access"
    suffix=".log"
    pattern="combined"
    renameOnRotate="true"
    requestAttributesEnabled="true"
    maxDays="90"
    conditionIf="org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.RemoteAddr"
/>
```