# Need to get remote ip of one who is accessing the web application

Tags: tomcat8, x-forwarded-for

I am trying to log website visitor application in tomcat logs
I have tried adding below lines of code in server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %F %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
```

I am getting the below output in the tomcat log.

> - 192.168.1.149 15 - - [24/Jul/2020:16:24:16 +0200] "GET /geonetwork/srv/eng/shib.user.login.noforward HTTP/1.0" 200 50

I need to get remote IP of one who is accessing the application

Comment: please share your server.xml

Comment: have you tried to check on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103673/how-to-log-client-ip-and-x-forwarded-for-ip-in-tomcat-access-log/48180469 ??

Comment: `<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
          <Context docBase="C:\MeDaResurser\bilder" path="/MeDa/bilder"/>
    <Context docBase="C:\MeDaResurser\htmlView" path="/MeDa/htmlView"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %F %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>`

Comment: Yes. I have tried on this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103673/how-to-log-client-ip-and-x-forwarded-for-ip-in-tomcat-access-log/48180469" @FahimBagar

Comment: what is your tomcat version?

Comment: tomcat version 8.0.45

Comment: @MahendranK Please [edit] extra details into the question. They're almost unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenario, your tomcat is **not behind any load balancer** or proxy or **behind one**. If your tomcat is not behind proxy or load balancer, it's already correct. For more precaution, maybe add `%a` so it can grab the remote ip address as stated in [Access_Log_Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %F %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

To

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %a %h %F %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

If you want to use `%h` for Remote host name, please set enableLookups="true" at connector

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
<Connector port="8080" 
....
    enableLookups="true"
      ....
/>
```

But in any case that the tomcat is behind proxy or load balancer, add more configuration like this:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" />

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" ....
```

The proxy default ip addresses that used by RemoteIpValve:

- 127.0.0.0/8
- 169.254.0.0/16
- 10.0.0.0/8
- 192.168.0.0/16

And maybe if your proxy is not listed here, add internalproxies configuration to catch the proxy:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
  internalProxies="172.16.0.10|172.16.0.11" />
```

Comment: I have tried both the methods, I am not getting the remote ip of the one who is accessing the web application